# Ad child menu item via functions.php in WP

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, woothemes

Ok, so I am using some PHP code in functions.php to dynamically ad custom (Login/Admin Logout) menu items to primary menu in WP, based on weather user is logged in or not. Here is the code I currently use:

```
// Custom menu (login/logout)
function asv_add_usermenu ($items, $args) {

    // user is logged in, display Admin and Logout options
    if ($_SESSION['tkadmin_adminauthenticated'] && $args->theme_location == 'primary-menu') {

        // ADMIN
        $items .= "<li id='admin-menu' class='sub-menu'><a href='/admin/'>Admin</a></li>";

        // LOGOUT
        $items .= "<li id='logout-menu' class='sub-menu'><a href='/logout/'>Logout</a></li>";

    // user it not logged in, display Login options
    } elseif (!$_SESSION['tkadmin_adminauthenticated'] && $args->theme_location == 'primary-menu') {

        // LOGIN
        $items .= "<li id='login-menu' class='sub-menu'><a href='/login/'>Login</a></li>";

    }
    return $items;
}

add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'asv_add_usermenu', 10, 2 );
```

My question is, how can I ad custom child menu items (sub-menus), which are shown as drop-down items once you click a menu item. I would like to ad a few sub menu items to Admin in the primary menu. So when the user is logged in, they will see the Admin menu (done already with provided code) in the primary menu and this Admin menu would have sub-menus, like Users, Invoices, etc.

So the drop down would look like this:

Admin

1. Users
2. Invoices
3. etc.

I am using woo canvas theme.